# Problem connecting to jupyter notebook server over ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ssh-tunnel

I used to be able to set up a connection from my home to my work machine's (different network) jupyter server just fine. It stopped working without any obvious reason. My macbook can still connect, so the remote is fine.

I set up  server with:
`jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8887`

And then I try to forward with:
`ssh -N -L localhost:8887:localhost:8887  $user@$host`

but this always times out:
`connect to host $host port 22: Connection timed out`

Logging into the remote machine via ssh terminal works fine. Any ideas how to find the issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to forward port 8887 to port 8887 on the same server?
If so why are you then trying to ssh on port 22, and not 8887?
Please try 'sudo netstat -tpln' to see what ports are open and add that to the question.
Also try 'telnet localhost <port number> on the relevant ports.

Comment: I am trying to forward port 8887 from a different server (work) to my home computer. At least if I understand your question right. I have not actively chosen port 22 for my ssh server to the remote server.
'telnet localhost:8887'  gave: could not resolve localhost:8887/telnet: Name or service not known.
'sudo netstat -tpln does not shown the port forwarded, but also not the ssh connection that I can establish with my terminal. Output partial:  
8387/python         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:48015         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8888
```

(You might get another number like 8889. If you get another then you have to change the number below as well.)

Then open a new terminal and enter: (remember to change remoteuser@remotehost)

```
ssh -N -f -L localhost:8889:localhost:8888 remoteuser@remotehost
```

Look at this post for more detailed information and a walkthrough: https://ljvmiranda921.github.io/notebook/2018/01/31/running-a-jupyter-notebook/